# Can I get the arguments passed to bazel itself?

Tags: bazel

I want to create some "build traceability" functionality, and include the actual bazel command that was run to produce one of my build artifacts. So if the user did this:

```
bazel run //foo/bar:baz --config=blah
```

I want to actually get the string `"bazel run //foo/bar:baz --config=blah"` and write that to a file during the build. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Stamping](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#workspace_status) is the "correct" way to get information like that into a Bazel build. Note the implications around caching though. You could also just write a wrapper script that puts the command line into a file or environment variable. Details of each approach below.

I can think of three ways to get the information you want via stamping, each with differing tradeoffs.

First way: Hijack [--embed_label](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--embed_label). This shows up in the `BUILD_EMBED_LABEL` stamping key. You'd add a line like `build:blah --embed_label blah` in your `.bazelrc`. This is easy, but that label is often used for things like `release_50`, which you might want to preserve.

Second way: hijack the hostname or username. These show up in the `BUILD_HOST` and `BUILD_USER` stamping keys. On Linux, you can write a shell script at `tools/bazel` which will automatically be used to wrap bazel invocations. In that shell script, you can use `unshare --uts --map-root-user`, which will work if the machine is set up to enable bazel's sandboxing. Inside that new namespace, you can easily change the hostname and then `exec` the real bazel binary, like the default `/usr/bin/bazel` shell script does. That shell script has full access to the command line, so it can encode any information you want.

Third way: put it into an environment variable and have a custom [--workspace_status_command](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--workspace_status_command) that extracts it into a stamping key. Add a line like `build:blah --action_env=MY_BUILD_STYLE=blah` to your `.bazelrc`, and then do `echo STABLE_MY_BUILD_STYLE ${MY_BUILD_STYLE}` in your workspace status script. If you want the full command line, you could have a `tools/bazel` wrapper script put that into an environment variable, and then use `build --action_env=MY_BUILD_STYLE` to preserve the value and pass it to all the actions.

Once you pick a stamping key to use, [src/test/shell/integration/stamping_test.sh](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/shell/integration/stamping_test.sh) in the Bazel source tree is a good example of writing stamp information to a file. Something like this:

```py
genrule(
  name = "stamped",
  outs = ["stamped.txt"],
  cmd = "grep BUILD_EMBED_LABEL bazel-out/volatile-status.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2 >\$@",
  stamp = True,
)
```

If you want to do it without stamping, just write the information to a file in the source tree in a `tools/bazel` wrapper. You'd want to put that file in your `.gitignore`, of course. `echo "$@" > cli_args` is all it takes to dump them to a file, and then you can use that as a source file like normal in your build. This approach is simplest, but interacts the most poorly with Bazel's caching, because everything that depends on that file will be rebuilt every time with no way to control it.